# How to randomly call a function within a given time interval ? - Python

Tags: python, database, function, time, simulator

I am creating a simulator which tries to simulate an office Door Sensor.
The office is usually open from **8.00am to 6.00pm.**
The function would give me timestamps when the door was opened and when the door was closed ( in Timestamps ). 
**The door takes 10 seconds to close.**

So I want to create a function which I would randomly call between **8.00am to 6.00pm.** That function would give me timestamps of when the door was opened and closed.

Simulator runs a loop per second , and I would want to call this function randomly between **8.00am to 6.00pm.**

I'd appreciate if you can suggest me a different approach.

Thanks.

UPDATED : Assume that the door will remain close with a `Sensor_Status : 0` until that function is called.
So I would like to name that function as `def DoorOpenAction:`

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler

sched = BackgroundScheduler()

def DoorOpenAction():
   print('I want to call this function anytime between 8.00am to 6.00pm')
   print('I also want to do this even if a day is passed')

sched.add_job(DoorOpenAction, 'interval', seconds=1)
sched.start()
```

Its tough Maybe ,
I wanna know how should I proceed with this.
I want to create a simulated DataSet

Comment: Post code of what you've tried already.

Comment: I have not coded this simulator yet. I want to create a time-series door sensor data set. I want to know If this approach is good to "almost" emulate a door sensor in real time.

Comment: Is the goal to check how many times the door was opened?

Comment: Yes. Assume that Door will remain close with `Status : 0` until that function is called.

Comment: maybe you want to put a function as a job, and use it within a crontab ?

Comment: @lalam check the updated question.

Comment: Do you want to call this function only once at all, in the specified time range?

Comment: @Attersson , No I want to call it multiple times. I can start with lets say , 2 times in an hour, but that hour has to random between 8.00am to 6.00pm

Answer (score 0):

You could do a random draw inside DoorOpenAction() to determine if you want to perform the action then or not.  You could adjust the likelihood to get the appropriate frequency.